# Global error message in php

Tags: php, scope

I have a problem with the understanding of variable scopes.

I've got a huge .php file with many $_POST validations (I know that isn't not good practise). Anyways I want a little html-part above all the code which outputs an error message. This message I want to change in every $_POST validation function.

**Example:**

```
if($ERR) {
    echo '<div class="error-message">'.$ERR.'</div>';
}
```

Now my functions are following in the same file.

```
if(isset($_POST['test']) {
    $ERR = 'Error!';
}

if(isset($_POST['test2'] {
    $ERR = 'Error 2!';
}
```

But that doesn't work. I think there's a huge missunderstanding and i'm ashamed.
Can you help me?

Comment: PHP works top down, it starts parsing your script at the top and works its way down to the bottom handling all lines sequential. You could place the html at the bottom of the script.

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['test']))` isn't a function. If you are running through your file procedurally then you're echoing `$ERR` before setting it. If you do have functions then post your actual code please.

Comment: hi please say what do you want to do? i will tell you a good way after that

Comment: @Tuim omg..that's the answer. ^^ Yes, my html code should go under all function so the error message in the functions will be above the code. Easy as that. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

I didnt catch your question but maybe this is your answer:

```
<body>
   <p id="error_message">
     <?php if(isset($ERR)){echo $ERR;} ?>
   </p>
 </body>
```

and I suggest you to learn how to work with **sessions**.
and you should know that $_Post will be empty on each **refresh** or **F5**

Answer (score 0):

You can do put the errors in array make them dynamic.

```
<?php
$error = array();

    if (!isset($_POST["test"]) || empty($_POST["test"])) {

        $error['test'] = "test Field is required";

    } else  if (!isset($_POST["test1"]) || empty($_POST["test1"])) {
      $error['test1'] = "test Field is required";

   }else{
        //do something else
    }
?>
```

You can also use switch statement instead of elseif which is neater.